# Do I need to secure the body of a REST request using oAuth?

Tags: security, rest, oauth

I'm building a REST API and using oAuth for authorization.  My question is do I need to do anything about the body of the request in the case of PUT and POST requests that contain data?  I'm using SSL if that makes any difference.

It seems to me that the url is verified by the oAuth signature, but the contents of the body could be anything.  I'm not sure if that's a problem, though, because if the URL is correctly signed then they have provided the correct credentials to do an insert or update.  I am using nonce to prevent replay attacks as well, but I want to avoid creating a security issue due to misunderstanding how to treat the request body.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: It sounds like what you're really asking is whether you should digitally sign the body of the request, so that your server can validate whether it's been modified by a malicious attacker while in transit. Is that about right?

I haven't worked with any REST APIs that do that - generally speaking, if the connection is secured and the request is properly authenticated, you're good. Assuming, of course, you're doing proper data validation, avoiding basic buffer overflow, injection attacks, etc...

Comment: Thanks, that's basically what I was thinking but it seems like it creates a man-in-the-middle vulnerability, as far as changing the payload.  It seems really unlikely, but I just wasn't sure if it's standard to sign it.  Sounds like it's not..?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer looking through some OAuth libraries.  It's not officially part of the spec but some services and libraries use "xoauth_body_signature" and "xoauth_body_signature_method" in the request headers to send a signature of the body contents.

Apparently there's some challenges implementing and discussions can be found by googling for xoauth_body_signature.  It doesn't seem like a lot of people are doing it.